# While runinng python code, my "import <module>" doesn't work even if it's installed

Tags: python, module

In my code I have:

```
import os
import discord
import openai
```

I used the correct command in CMD to install them, and even checked my file explorer and found the file folders for these modules.

When I run my code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bleepname\Documents\.my_bot\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
```

and then when I take out `import discord` I get the same message but instead of "No module named 'discord'," it's "No module named 'openai'.

can anybody identify the problem and possibly give me an answer? thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you *think* you have installed the modules properly, but you have not for whichever Python installation you are using to execute the code.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know how I would fix that?

Comment: To respond to above:

You clearly have not installed these for the python version you are running.
Since you are on windows, try `py -3.11 -m pip install []` and then `py -3.11 [file]` This way, you'll get the same executable.

Comment: Responding to Egeau: Thanks, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are installing your modules on the same python installation as you are running your code.

If you are running your code with `python file.py`, then try doing `python -m pip install discord`

If you are running your python via python3, or py3, or otherwise, then use that instead. You are likely using a pip that is not on the installation that you are executing your code base in.

If you are using Visual Studio Code, you can switch between registered python installations in the bottom left, but either way, this method of doing your installs will guarantee it is on the same installation as the python that you're actually executing.

Comment: One side note: 
On windows, using the py launcher `py -3.11` e.g. to get to the python executable would be preferred.  Windows is a bit iffy with these things, which is why the launcher exists and is installed by default. :P I have never had issues on Linux either, but I have helped enough people on Windows to know this can go wrong there. :P

Comment: Good note! Thanks @Egeau